# auto select using jquery not works if data is collected using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I loaded the selection data from database automatically using ajax

```
 <div class="row-form">
          <div class="span2">Condition:</div>
          <div class="span4 input-prepend">
          <span class="add-on blue"><i class="icon-arrow-down icon-white"></i></span>
          <select name="condition" id="condition" class="validate[required]" >
           </select>
          </div>
      </div>


    //ajax function to load condition to select box
$.ajax({
    url:'search/condition.php',
    type:'POST',
    async:true,
    success: function(data){
        $("#condition").html(data);
    }
});
```

PHP Code for ajax :-

```
<?php
require("../dbconnect.php");

    $qry="SELECT * FROM  condition_master";
        $rs=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
       $data .= "<option value=''>Select condition</option>";
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
          $des=$row['condition_des'];
          $data .= "<option value='$des'>$des</option>";
      }

      echo $data;
?>
```

its loading properly.. but while trying to auto select the condition using jquery its not selecting properly

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#condition").val('used');
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact you shouldn't really return HTML from a web service like this, you need to call `.val()` after you have populated the `<select>`:

```
success: function(data){
        $("#condition").html(data).val('used');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make this fungction

```
function loadcondition (getFile){
$.ajax({
url: getFile,
beforeSend: function (){
$("#condition") .html("<img src=\"style/img/ajax.gif\" />");
},
success: function(data){
$("#condition") .html(data);
}
});
}
```

use it

loadcondition ("search/condition.php");

Comment: thank you, success: function(data){
    $("#condition").html(data).val('used');
}

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the success

```
success: function(data){
    $("#condition").html(data).val('used');
}
```